# How to select object with dynamic value in xpath in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, dynamic, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Can you help me to select an object in Selenium Webdriver which xpath value is dynamical. The xpath is

```
  dd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='defaultSwatchContainer_wxnit']/div/div/ul/li[list]"))
```

Here "wxnit" after "defaultSwatchContainer_" changes with every page load. 
Thanks

Comment: What is `li[list]` about? I don't know this notation.

Comment: @RenéLink li[list] means an li node which must have an attribute 'list'.

Comment: @VikasNehaOjha But the `@` is missing, isn't it? I think it should be `li[@list]`.

Comment: @RenéLink, apologies, my mistake.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me out - regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use the xpath [starts-with](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with) function

```
"//*[starts-with(@id, 'defaultSwatchContainer_')]/div/div/ul/li[list]"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'defaultSwatchContainer_')]/div/div/ul/li[list]"))
```